# How do I crash Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS deliberately?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, crash

I'm trying to crash an instance on AWS so that I can simulate what happens when it gets *'stuck'*.

I tried the top suggestions here [How to cause kernel panic with a single command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66197/how-to-cause-kernel-panic-with-a-single-command) but unfortunately they were not successful.

Comment: From the referenced page, did you try this: `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/mem` ?  And what happened after the sysrq trigger?

Answer (score 3):

This wasn't one of the official answers to [How to cause kernel panic with a single command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66197/how-to-cause-kernel-panic-with-a-single-command), but it was referenced in a comment, and it should cause the system to crash.

Run the following forkbomb command at your bash shell:

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

The system will continue to create new processes until the system hangs.

Or you can try the following python script:

```
import os
while True: os.fork()
```